# Fix a (Today) Date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a file with a VB macro that puts a `TODAY()` formula in a cell when I click a button. The formula is volatile and updates every time the sheet is calculated. Instead, I would like to lock the value so that it only shows the date on which the macro was executed. So, if I open the file tomorrow, it will be the same value. How can I do this?

Comment: bAN is looking to prevent the Excel function `=TODAY()`, which is inserted into his sheet by a macro, from updating. Rather than `=TODAY()`, he's looking for a formula that will enter a date/time stamp and leave it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the value property of the cell:

```
TheCell.Value = Date
```

Date = Today

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go in and modify the VBA code in the Click event off the button.
I'd create a second button if you want Today's date in the cell, and disable it from the first button.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way of doing this -

Select the cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

Another trick - 
Under the same conditions, if you want to insert the current time in `HH: MM` format:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> in the cell.

(FOR MAC: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>)

Comment: The question asks how this is done inside a macro, not from the keyboard.